# Is this "TODO" supposed to be at the bottom of the page?

Tags: bug, status-completed

I just happened to notice this at the bottom of a question. Never noticed it before and was curious, is this normally there?

[image: example TODO]

Comment: Looks like somone tried using a `//` comment in html which is useless

Comment: It's a network-wide issue, apparently: ["// TODO sg: TMP solution until we are confident..." showing up on question pages on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375317/461068).

Comment: When the backend developer gets to the frontend code

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Per [Adam Lear's response on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375324/335251), this bug has been fixed:

> This is part of our new tradition here at Stack Overflow... Whoops Wednesday.
>
> Thanks for the report! The fix is out now.